Field data types change to text when exporting to CSV with 'Add saved file to map'
In QGIS 3.32.2-Lima when exporting a non-spatial layer, e.g. the output from the Statistics by category tool, to CSV with the 'Add saved file to map' checked, the data types of all fields of the new layer change to Text (string). If I remove the new layer and import the CSV file, the data types are correct. In this example, the field names are 'vegName' (string) and the summary statistics fields (which are integer and double). Screenshots of the export dialogue and the resulting field types are shown below.
I can work around by unchecking 'Add saved file to map' and importing the CSV file, but it creates extra steps.
Anyone know why this happens?



In the "Save Vector Layer as" Dialog choose the CREATE_CSVT Option YES. This way, the field data types are saved in the csv.


Thanks that works. It seems odd though that this setting is needed when the field types are recognised correctly when the CSV file is imported without having the csvt file.
